# progress bar in webview keeps loading even after web page finished loading

Tags: java, android, webview

**Here is my code**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView view;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    String url = "http://www.carsaleindiaofficial.com/?m=1";
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

}

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);


        //if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("carsaleindiaofficial.com/?m=1")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        view.loadUrl(view.getUrl());

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The progress bar and webview works fine but when the page is finished loading the progress bar still remains? When I have loaded the page the progress bar visibility doesn't dissapear/change to GONE? Where is the error?
Ive tried both progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); but nothin seems to work.

Comment: use async Task to open webView and when dismiss your peogress Dialogn in onPostExecute()

Comment: @Arjun Bajapi see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using customizing webclient. you use default webclient. your problem is replace this.

```
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

add this

```
view.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
```

and also

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

not

```
view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

full code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView view;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maine);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    String url = "http://www.carsaleindiaofficial.com/?m=1";
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    //view.loadUrl(url);
    view.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/");
   // view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web.html");

}

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("pageFinished", "yesss");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maine, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        view.loadUrl(view.getUrl());

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: still no luck.. :( ive tried every thing. pb either keeps loading or completely disappears.. :( & using  view.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient()); opens the url in the browser not in my app. :(

Comment: The page is very heavy. you can check on some other link.

Comment: i chekd it on linkd in signup page.. but its still loading.. ive used dat page to fool people.. on that page regular people wont be able to figure out the continuous loading bug..

Comment: i cant understand what is the problem with my code.. as a simple progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE) should do the work.. :(

Comment: @ArjunBajpai the problem is onPageFinished not called. check the updated code.

Comment: wait until the page load. on my emulator it takes 15 min. The page is very heavy.

Comment: thank you sooo much @arun your updated code works... :)

Answer (score 1):

just changed WebViewClient to MyWebViewClient, progressBar to progressBar1 & ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity and every code seems to work :) thank again every1.. :) @Devendra & @akhil :)

my final code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity {



private WebView view;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    String url = "http://www.carsaleindiaofficial.com/?m=1";
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

}

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.i("pageFinished", "yesss");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("progressBar", "Gone");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("progressBar", "Visible");
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        Log.i("ShldOvrideUrl", "working");
        return true;
    }

   }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        view.loadUrl(view.getUrl());

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: it seem work, but I get a little problem here, when the apps first loading (load on first page) the progress bar didn't gone, but instead after I move to next page, finally its gone, is it possible to make progress bar gone on first load? or it just cant? my code its likely same with yours, without the back button

Answer (score 0):

After intent of webview url you have to write `progressbar.visibility="View.GONE"`

Comment: progressbar.setVisibility="View.GONE"

Comment: use progressbar.Dismiss();  after  view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: adding progressbar.setVisibility="View.GONE" or progressbar.Dismiss(); pops out an error saying "cannot resolve method". While adding progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); makes the progress bar disappear completely..

Comment: progressBar.dismiss();

Comment: using progressBar.dismiss(); pops out an error saying cannot resolve method dismiss()

Comment: mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Recovering Data. Please wait...");  Dynamically add ProgressDialog. and after webview content display add  mProgressDialog.dismiss(); It works for me

Comment: error pops up saying cannot resolve method getActivity().. i think the code is not able to sense whether the webview has finished loading the url or not..

Comment: use this in place of getActivity()

Comment: use GetApplicationContext() in place of this

Comment: again the error pops up saying cannot resolve method GetApplicationContext()

Comment: just show me what r u doing?? post ur progessDialog code

Comment: import android.app.ProgressDialog; private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GetApplicationContext(), "", "Recovering Data. Please wait..."); view.getContext().startActivity(intent); mProgressDialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FGallery.this.progressBar.setProgress(100);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FGallery.this.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}
```

This is working for me. you can set it as `WebViewClient`.